# Pyside how to set multi shorcuts to one pushButton

Tags: button, pyqt, pyside

I have one pushButton on my app, I want to trigger it when I press 'Return' or 'Enter'(num-pad) keyboard. I tried many way, but failed..

```
   self.ui.PushButton1.setShortcut('return')
   # I want like: (['return', 'enter'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `setShortcut()` if you want multiple shortcuts for the same button. Calling it the second time will clear the first shortcut.
You have to use multiple `QShortCut` and connect their `activated` signal.

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt6.QtGui import QShortcut


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pb = QPushButton('push')
        pb.clicked.connect(lambda: print('clicked'))

        short1 = QShortcut('return', self)
        short1.activated.connect(pb.click)

        short2 = QShortcut('backspace', self)
        short2.activated.connect(pb.click)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(pb)


app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Notes:
I used 'backspace' as a second key because I don't have numpad 'enter' on my keyboard.
On PyQt5, you have to import `QShortcut` from `QtWidgets`

Since you connect both shortcuts to the same slot, you can shorten the code like this:

```
    for key in ('return', 'backspace'):
        QShortcut(key, self).activated.connect(pb.click)
```